# How did it happen that one user can access files of another user's account on the same computer?

Tags: security, users

On the same computer, I have two user accounts, one for work and the other personal.

On Ubuntu 18.04 I can access, for some reason, files from one account if I am logged in in to the other (from the command line, or programs just open them).

How can I prevent this? How did this happen?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 changes the /home directory permissions so each user's /home directory is no longer globally readable.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is permissions.  The command

ls -l

will show permissions on a file.  It's not unusual for default permissions to include the ability of everybody being able to read.  It's also very easy to change those default permissions. This is an important topic in the unix world and much has been written on "linux permissions". Specific questions about permissions can be answered here.